# django management command + yui compressor

Tags: django, yui-compressor

Can I call yui compressor: java -jar yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar [options] [input file] from a django management command and if so how do I go about doing it?

I develop locally on Window and host on Linux, so this seem like a solution that will work on both.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Van Gale's answer, it's most certainly possible.  Here are the ingredients:

- An app that is in INSTALLED APPS
- The proper directory structure
- A python file to act as the command which inherits off of a Django management command class

Here's generally how this works...

When manage.py runs, if it does not find the command say "manage.py yui_compress" it searches through the installed apps.  It looks in each app to see if app.management.commands exists, and then checks if there is a file "yui_compress.py" in that module.  If so, it will initiate the class in that python file and use that.

So, it ends up looking like this...

```
app
   \management
        \commands
            yui_compress.py
```

Where yui_compress.py contains...

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = "Does my special action."
    requires_model_validation = False

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        # Execute whatever code you want here
        pass
```

Of course 'app' needs to be in thE INSTALLED APPS inside of settings.py.

But then, Van does make a good suggestion to find a tool which already does what you want. :)

Comment: +1 Nice answer, I was wanting to sketch out how to do a command but didn't have enough time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I understand how to setup the management commands, but was wondering about the: NoArgsCommand and what to put inside the: def handle_noargs method?

Comment: What goes in there is whatever code you want to be run when the command is run.  Here's an example from South -- http://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/src/tip/south/management/commands/convert_to_south.py  So in your case you could, for example, have it recursively search the MEDIA_ROOT folder, find all files ending in CSS, run them through the YUI compressor, then save them as [[originalname]]_compressed.css.

Comment: yeah, but how do I run the command: java -jar yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar from that method?  Sorry, I just can't find an docs on NoArgsCommand stuff.  Thanks!

Comment: It's just regular Python that you stick in there.  For example, subprocess.Popen -- http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to write the command part yourself.  The best way to go about this would be to see how the stock commands are implemented or look at a project like [django-command-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/)

However, an even better solution (i.e. less work) would be to use a project like [django-compress](http://code.google.com/p/django-compress/) that already defines a management command `synccompress` that will call yui compressor.

Answer (score 0):

I recently added a YUI Compressor processor to django-mediasync.

If you'd like to use django-mediasync itself, here's the project page:
https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-mediasync

If you'd like to see the YUI Compressor command as a reference, here's a copy/paste from it (in case the paths change in the future)...

```
from django.conf import settings
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def _yui_path(settings):
    if not hasattr(settings, 'MEDIASYNC'):
        return None
    path = settings.MEDIASYNC.get('YUI_COMPRESSOR_PATH', None)
    if path:
        path = os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(path))
    return path

def css_minifier(filedata, content_type, remote_path, is_active):
    is_css = (content_type == 'text/css' or remote_path.lower().endswith('.css'))
    yui_path = _yui_path(settings)
    if is_css and yui_path and is_active:
        proc = Popen(['java', '-jar', yui_path, '--type', 'css'], stdout=PIPE,
                     stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(input=filedata)
        return str(stdout)

def js_minifier(filedata, content_type, remote_path, is_active):
    is_js = (content_type == 'text/javascript' or remote_path.lower().endswith('.js'))
    yui_path = _yui_path(settings)
    if is_js and yui_path and is_active:
        proc = Popen(['java', '-jar', yui_path, '--type', 'js'], stdout=PIPE,
                     stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(input=filedata)
        return str(stdout)
```